# (MAUI, iOS) SKLottieView shows static image when I came from another page and doesn't start :)

Tags: maui

SKLottieView doesn't play animation if I was on another page, just a static image. I can guess it doesn't play in background, so if it doesn't move then how do I run it again once I navigated to a page?

[A small video sample on OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtDUa3oxb3BY6FZwVLzNSIk6ALWP?e=Eey38m)

Comment: Possibly https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/issues/142

Comment: **Add to question** the relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask